# Get the ProgID for a VB6 dll

Tags: dll, asp-classic, vb6

I have a need to create an object to a DLL(vb6) that I created using MS VB6 editor in a classic ASP page.

```
set obj = Server.CreateObject("ProgID")
```

Now I was generally under the assumption that the program ID was the **projectName.ClassName**

That is now the person who was maintaining the code before me seems to have coded. And the application is working.

But when I try the same, IIS is not able to create an object. I did register the Dll and I'm running win 7 64 bit.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your DLL 64 bit? If not, are you using a 32 bit application pool?

Comment: Yes its a 32 bit DLL. I thought compiling the code in a 64 bit OS will make it a 64 bit DLL. I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize, I figured out the problem. I had missed giving the iis permission to the read the DLL. Also the DLL was a 32 bit DLL and I had to change the iis settings to accept 32 bit DLLs.

So to answer my own question, the program ID is **projectname.classname**.